# Internal error: org.jetbrains.concurrency.MessageError: Helper script failed on remote: _jb_debug_helper is not defined

Tags: debugging, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

WebStorm 2017.2.1

> Internal error: org.jetbrains.concurrency.MessageError: Helper script failed on remote: _jb_debug_helper is not defined

I am getting above error when tries to run debugger and look for certain properties in 'local' section. Even a single watch expression added to it does not return the result.

Answer (score 2):

the issue is tracked as [WEB-27884](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-27884), please follow it for updates